# Removing required approvers from VSTS pull request

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

We are using VSTS together with git for source control, etc.  I have a VSTS/git pull request that has several redundant required approvers.  Several of them have already approved the pull request.  I'd like to go ahead and complete the pull request.

I can remove the extraneous required approvers by clicking on the little X beside each name in VSTS.  However, when I then try to complete the pull request VSTS re-adds them back to the pull request.  Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you share the detailed steps? I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's hard to do without you having access to our companies VSTS.  The settings on the develop branch are that we need two approvers on pull requests.  On this one the developer added several other people as approvers.  I'd like to go ahead and complete the pull request.  It will allow me to remove the required approvers from the pull request, but when I click on the "Complete Pull Request" button it gives me a "The pull request needs to be approved by all required reviewers before it can be completed." message and then it re-adds the required approvers to the pull request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error messages you get, you are trying to delete the required approvers that are specified from "Control Panel\Version Control\Branch Policies".
[image]

However, The required approvers cannot be deleted. You can only delete the approvers specified when create the pull request. You can un-check the "Required" option if you do want to delete them.

Comment: The Control Panel\Version Control\Branch Policies only applies to new pull requests correct?  Is there a way to make the change to existing pull requests?

Comment: @Eric It applies to the existing pull requests too. By the way, unchecking "required" option only allow you to complete the pull request with the approve from these approvers. Their name will still show in the pull request. If you don't want to show them, you need to uncheck "Enabled" option.